# Short story about a (sheperd?) boy who stops alien invasion by finding a cave with a planetary defense post

Tags: story-identification

Plot goes roughly like this: boy lives in "down to earth" society and is, i think, a village shepherd. Then he "cries wolf" and loses trust of his village, he either runs away or is forced into exile. He finds shelter in a cave that houses backup planetary defense post from times long forgotten, and he speaks to it when alien invasion starts, activating defenses and saving the planet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is "Sign of the Wolf" by Fred Saberhagen, one of his Berserker stories. Per [ISFDB](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?54090), it was originally published in the May 1965 edition of *If* magazine, and has been republished many times in collections.

You can find what I think is the [complete text of the story] [2](http://www.berserker.com/story-wolfcover.htm) online, but here's a quote:

> "Here I am." Duncan fell on his knees before the metal thing that
> bellowed. In front of the god-shape lay woven twigs and eggshells, so
> old as to be hardly more than dust. Once priests had sacrificed here,
> and then they had forgotten this god.
>
> "Here I am," said Duncan again, in a louder voice.
>
> The god heeded him, for the deafening shouting stopped.
>
> In a glassy place beside the god strange things appeared: there was a
> huge ball, with little red specks crawling its surface, and a little
> red ball the size of a fist moving toward it.
>
> "Response acknowledged, from defense control alternate 9,864," said
> the god. "Planetary defenses now under control of post 9,864."

Comment: The whole May 1965 issue of *If* is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/1965-05_IF#page/n51/mode/2up).

Comment: Website created the same year as the story was first published.